# I want to have 2 rows in a column where first row has only 1 large element due to which lot of space is wasted in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[UI of my flutter app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDmX9.jpg)

I want to shift insert and search button upward which are in a row but it is constrained by above row which contains only one big element(the circular slider) due to which the bounding box of  whole row  has increased. So, lot of space is wasted. What can be the workaround for this, I want to have variable size widgets in a row but the row bounding box should be fitted to individual widgets rather than taking the size of the biggest element.

```
 Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text('Available : '),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      taxi.available = (taxi.available == 1) ? 0 : 1;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Availabilitybutton(taxi.available)),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text('Condition : '),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            ),
            SleekCircularSlider(
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                initialValue: 5,
                appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
                    size: 100,
                    startAngle: 180,
                    angleRange: 180,
                    customColors: CustomSliderColors(
                        trackColor: Colors.black38,
                        progressBarColors: [
                          Colors.green,
                          Colors.yellowAccent,
                          Colors.redAccent
                        ],
                        dynamicGradient: false)),
                innerWidget: (value) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${value.round()}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                onChange: (double value) {
                  taxi.carCondition = value.round();
                  print(value);
                })
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    choice = 0;
                    _save();
                  });
                  updateExpenseView();
                },
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    color: Colors.black38,
                    child: Text(
                      'Insert',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ))),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    choice = 1;
                    _search(id: d_id);
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    color: Colors.black38,
                    child: Text(
                      'Search',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )))
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Warp the row with a container and give it a fixed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reduce row size by clipping the bigger circular slider element, since I had displayed only a semi-circle but the widget gives space for the whole circle.

```
ClipRect(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                heightFactor: 0.8,
                child: SleekCircularSlider(
                    min: 0,
                    max: 10,
                    initialValue: 5,
                    appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
                        size: 100,
                        startAngle: 180,
                        angleRange: 180,
                        customColors: CustomSliderColors(
                            trackColor: Colors.black38,
                            progressBarColors: [
                              Colors.green,
                              Colors.yellowAccent,
                              Colors.redAccent
                            ],
                            dynamicGradient: false)),
                    innerWidget: (value) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(
                          '${value.round()}',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    onChange: (double value) {
                      taxi.carCondition = value.round();
                    }),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Rows will accommodate the biggest widget specified.

Instead how about you split the row containing the slider into 2 columns and the left column could further be split into 2 rows. The bottom row here can be used to put the insert and search widgets.

[image: See below image]

Comment: But then the Condition Container will not appear in line with the displayed number